# Canonical way to use MikTeX via appveyor

Tags: miktex, windows

I'm trying to use continuous integration with appveyor but I'm unable to run `pdflatex`. I considered myself reasonably competent with MikTeX up until now, though perhaps this is more a powershell problem.

I was able to install and run TeX Live through appveyor but I'd like to test MikTeX.

#### Attempt 1: docker

I attempted to use MikTeX's `docker` image (https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-docker) but it appears to be only usable for GNU/Linux:

```
build_script:
  - docker pull miktex/miktex
  - docker volume create --name miktex
  - docker run -ti \
      -v miktex:/miktex/.miktex \
      -v `pwd`:/miktex/work \
      miktex/miktex \
      pdflatex Report.tex
```

Results in:

```
>    docker pull miktex/miktex
>    Using default tag: latest
>    latest: Pulling from miktex/miktex
>    image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform
>    Command exited with code 1
>    7z a failure.zip *.Rcheck\*
```

### Attempt 2: via chocolatey

```
init:
    ps:
       choco install miktex.portable
       refreshenv

script:
  - pdflatex Report.tex
```

Result:

> 'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

You can assume that `Report.tex` compiles.

Comment: I myself have only used Travis CI, but there seem a few repositories to install MiKTeX on AppVeyor (e.g., https://github.com/thomasjo/appveyor-miktex)

Comment: @yudai-nkt: Unfortunately that script does not work any more, as the installer is now suffixed with a version.

Answer (score 1):

[doxygen](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen) has a working appveyor miktex install in  https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/appveyor.yml

Interesting bits:

```
install:
  # Static url: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/321#issuecomment-496286866
  # The setup is small enough, and does not need to be cached
  - appveyor-retry appveyor DownloadFile  https://miktex.org/download/win/miktexsetup-x64.zip
  - 7z e miktexsetup-x64.zip
  - appveyor-retry miktexsetup.exe --local-package-repository=C:\miktex-repository --package-set=essential download
  - miktexsetup.exe --local-package-repository=C:\miktex-repository --package-set=essential --shared install
  - refreshenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'canonical'. But this should work:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
image: Visual Studio 2017
install:
  - ps: choco install -y miktex
  - cmd:  refreshenv

build_script:
  - cmd: pdflatex .\Report.tex
```

Comment: The problem about chocolatey is that the miktex packages are not always up to date. So you might get lucky and end up on a server that has not yet deleted the old file. Otherwise the installation will fail. Pretty annoying.